# Запрос - вывести данные из двух SQL таблиц с определёнными условиями

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, таблицы

Ребят привет! Давно не работал с SQL и подзабыл нюансы.
Есть 2 таблы:

Client, Order

В Клиенте у нас

```
id (int)
born_at(timestamp)
Email(varchar)
```

в Ордер у нас

```
id(int)
Client_id(int)
Created_at(timestamp)
Paid_at(timestamp)
```

Нужно сделать запрос, что бы он возвращал таблицу с 3 колонками
Email клиента, дата первого заказа, дата последнего заказа. И вывести тех клиентов, которые были созданы с начала 2014 года.

Comment: покажите, как вы пробовали написать запрос ?  Видится следующее: подзапрос на извлечение последних заказов по каждому клиенту, подзапрос на извлечение первых заказов по каждому клиенту. Затем пара left join и where по дате рождения клиента.

Comment: *вывести тех клиентов, которые были созданы с начала 2014 года.* В таблице клиентов нет таких данных (если не считать, что "был создан" == "родился", конечно)... а предполагать, что дата создания клиента - это дата его первого заказа, мягко говоря, не очень правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
select
      [client].[email] as [email],
      min( [order].[created_at]) as [firts_order_date],
      max( [order].[created_at]) as [last_order_date],
from [client]
     inner join [order]
     on [client].[id] = [order].[client_id]
group by
     [client].[email]
having
     min( [order].[created_at]) >= '2014-01-01'
```

Считаю что email уникальный и дата заказа это created_at. На счёт когда были созданы client подберите правильное поле я установил первую order.created_at. Вы сами решите когда был создан client.